Is it possible to use abstract groups to generalize DSA, ECDSA and EdDSA signature creation and verification?
It is known, that
DSA algorithm is defined as:
Bob

Creates private $x$ and public $Y=G^x\bmod p$ keys, where $G$ - generator, $p$ - group prime order

Selects random value $k$ from $1
\le k\le q-1$

$X=G^k\bmod p$ and $r=X\bmod q$

$e=Hash(m)$, where $Hash$ - hash func, $m$ - data to hash

$s=(1/k)*(e+x*r)\bmod q$

Sends $(r,s,m,Y,G,q,p)$ to Alice


Alice

$e=Hash(m)$

$w=(1/s)\bmod q$

$a=e*w\bmod q$ and $b=r*w\bmod q$

$X=G^a*Y^b\bmod p$

$v=X\bmod q$

Signature is valid if $v==r$


ECDSA algorithm is defined as:
Bob

Creates private $z$ and public $Y=G*z$ keys, where $G$ - generator, i.e curve base point, $p$ - group prime order

Selects random value $k$ from $1
\le k\le q-1$

$R=k*G$

$e=Hash(m)$, where $Hash$ - hash func, $m$ - data to hash

$r=R_x\bmod p$, where $R_x$ - is $x$ coordinate of point $R(x,y)$

$s=(1/k)*(e+z*r)\bmod p$

Sends $(r,s,m,Y,G,p)$ to Alice


Alice

$e=Hash(m)$

$w=(1/s)\bmod q$

$a=e*w\bmod q$ and $b=r*w\bmod q$

$X=G*a+Y*b$

$c=X_x\bmod p$, where $X_x$ - $x$ coordinate of a point $X(x,y)$

Signature is valid if $c==r$


EdDSA algorithm is defined as:
Bob

Creates private $z$ and public $Y=G*z$ keys, where $G$ - generator, i.e curve base point, $p$ - group prime order

$h=Hash(z)$, where $Hash$ - is a hash func

$r=Hash(h[32:]\mathbin\|m)$, where $m$ - data to hash, $\mathbin\|$ - is bytes concatenation

$R=r*G$

$s=r+Hash(R\mathbin\|Y\mathbin\|m)*z$

Sends $(R,s,m,Y,G,p)$ to Alice


Alice

$p=Hash(R\mathbin\|Y\mathbin\|m)$

$A=p*G$

$B=R+Y*s$

Signature is valid if $A==B$


Problem
Looking at these algorithms I cannot find any similarities that I could abstract over algebraic groups. Especially interested in how can I get these $X_x$ or $R_x$ in ECDSA using algebraic groups, they should be group elements and not scalars, shoudn't they?
So my overall goal is to have two distinct functions: Sign() and Verify(), where inside I can only operate using algebraic group operations like:

Operation() - group operation
Scale() - in case of multiplicative group it is $X^y\bmod p$, and in case of additive group it is $y*X$


@fgrieu thanks for hints and typing errors in formulas, updated. But question still remains, is it possible to abstract DSA, ECDSA, EdDSA by algebraic groups in such way that is used only single Sign() and Verify() functions, where inside are only group elements' operations are allowed? Just the same way, as we can abstract it in EC/Discrete Log/Ed25519 ElGamal and will work fine

Your impression is correct: DSA and ECDSA cannot really be defined over abstract groups since they both use operations other than group operations. In that sense, they're rather inelegant schemes, that were designed to circumvent Schnorr's patent on the correct way to do group-based "Fiat-Shamir" signatures. EdDSA basically follows the correct way, since it was proposed after the patents expired.

@MehdiTibouchi: while I think you are largely right as to why we got DSA rather than Schnorr signature becoming standard, and then (thus) ECDSA, it's also clear to me that DSA is heavily inspired by ElGamal signature, which predates Schnorr's patent. DSA can be seen as ElGamal signature adapted to a Schnorr group (and with a hash of the message). ElGamal signature, DSA and ECDSA all share a summary reduction modulo the group order of something other than a hash, which at least complicates security analysis.

@fgrieu I guess you're right guys! DSA wasn't designed to be used with abstraction over algebraic group, despite it uses them:) And also there is a complex operation $G^k\bmod q$, which actually brings group element into a scalar space. In such case there is simply no other way to go. Also, EdDSA has completely different algorithm which doesn't have any similarities to ECDSA or DSA. This leads to fact that DSA, ECDSA and EdDSA should be implemented via abstraction over signingkey itself and not a group. Thank you all!

Re-updated: DSA uses as the abstract group the subgroup of order $q$ of a group of order $p-1$. It works$\bmod p$ but makes no use of addition modulo $p$, thus there's no group of order $p$ involved in DSA as currently stated in it's key generation. In the description made of ECDSA, all$\bmod p$ should be$\bmod q$. In signature, standard terms for your Bob is signer, your Alice is verifier.

Continued: It's essential to distinguish scalar multiplication $$ as in $R=r∗G$ from integer multiplication as in $a=e∗w\bmod q$, and addition of group elements Operation() as in the $+$ of in $Ga+Yb$, from addition of integers as in the $+$ of $e+zr$. It's customary to separate establishment of group parameters and public key, from signature generation and verification, because there is no operational sense to sending public key and signature together. The description of EdDSA's key generation does not match the standard description (actually a hash is involved).


Is it possible to use abstract groups to generalize DSA, ECDSA and EdDSA signature creation and verification?

Yes. But towards that it is essential to systematically distinguish:

the abstract finite group used, that I'll note $(\mathbb G,\mathbin{\dot+})$, of prime order $q$, with elements including a generator $G$ and neutral element $\mathcal O$.
the well-known finite field of integers modulo $q$ that I'll note $(\mathbb F_q,+,\cdot)$.

The group's internal law $\mathbin{\dot+}$ is the question's Operation(). On top of that primitive the question's Scale(), which is known as scalar multiplication, can be defined and efficiently implemented as: $\forall\,i\in\mathbb F_q$ and $\forall\,U\in\mathbb G$
$$i*U=\begin{cases}
\mathcal O&\text{for }i=0\\
U&\text{for }i=1\\
V\mathbin{\dot+}V\text{ with }V=(i/2)*U&\text{for other even }i\\
((i-1)*U)\mathbin{\dot+}U&\text{for other }i\\
\end{cases}$$
The additive subgroup $(\mathbb F_q,+)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb G,\mathbin{\dot+})$ thru transforming $i\in\mathbb F_q$ into $i*G\in\mathbb G$. This bijection can be computed in time polynomial in $\log q$ only in the forward direction. The DLP and CDH assumptions are assumed to hold in $\mathbb G$, but not in any subgroup (additive or multiplicative) of $\mathbb F_q$. It holds $\forall\,i,j\in\mathbb F_q$ and $\forall\,U,V\in\mathbb G$
$$\begin{align}
(i+j)*U&=(i*U)\mathbin{\dot+}(i*U)\\
j*(U\mathbin{\dot+}V)&=(j*U)\mathbin{\dot+}(j*V)\\
(i\cdot j)*U&=i*(j*U)
\end{align}$$
And, depending on the algorithm, further building blocks are necessary.


Looking at these algorithms I cannot find any similarities that I could abstract over algebraic groups

That's possible for DSA and ECDSA, within the above framework. They differ only in the choice of the group $\mathbb G$, and of an ad-hoc function $f:\,\mathbb G\setminus\{\mathcal O\}\to\mathbb F_q$.

DSA: the group is a Schnorr group of prime order $q$, obtained as the subgroup of order $q$ of the multiplicative group modulo a prime $p$, with $q$ dividing $p-1$, and $p\gg q$. Elements $U\in\mathbb G$ are $U\in\mathbb F_p$ satisfying $U^q=1$ computed in $\mathbb F_p$, and the group law for $\mathbb G$ is defined as $U\mathbin{\dot+}V=U\cdot V$ with the right-hand size computed in $\mathbb F_p$ (this is why DSA's group is typically noted multiplicatively as in the question, when here we note it as $\dot+\,$ for the purpose of abstracting the group). The ad-hoc function $f$ is $f(U)=U\bmod q$ with the integer representative# of $U$ in $[0,p)$.
ECDSA: the group is an Elliptic Curve group, obtained as the subgroup of prime order $q$ of an Elliptic Curve over some finite base field. See sec1 for the construction of the group and it's "point addition" internal law $\mathbin{\dot+}$, sec2 for some common parameters. Restricting our description of ECDSA to the base field being a prime field $\mathbb F_p$ for some suitable $p$, an element of the full elliptic curve other than $\mathcal O$ is a pair $(X_U,Y_U)$ of integers in $\mathbb F_p$ satisfying the curve's equation, and those in $\mathbb G$ are those with $q*U=\mathcal O$. The ad-hoc function $f$ is $f(U)=X_U\bmod q$ with the integer representative# of $X_U$ in $[0,p)$.

DSA and ECDSA can then be described in a unified manner as:

Signer and verifier agree on the group $(\mathbb G,\mathbin{\dot+})\,$: nature, parameters including order $q$, generator $G$, representation of an element of $\mathbb G$ (for the public key) and of $\mathbb F_q$ (for signature components); an ad-hoc function $f:\,\mathbb G\setminus\{\mathcal O\}\to\mathbb F_q\,$; and a hash $\operatorname{Hash}:\,\{0,1\}^*\to\mathbb F_q$.
Signer generates (private, public) keys pair $(x,Y)$ with $x$ a secret random in $\mathbb F_q\setminus\{0\}$, $Y=x*G$, and communicates $Y$ to verifier with integrity.
For each message $m\in\{0,1\}^*$, signer

computes $e=\operatorname{Hash}(m)$
generates uniformly random secret $k\in\mathbb F_q\setminus\{0\}$
computes $r=f(k*G)$ in $\mathbb F_q$ and if $r=0$ reiterates from 2
computes $s=k^{-1}\cdot(e+r\cdot x)$ in $\mathbb F_q$ and if $s=0$ reiterates from 2
outputs signature $(r,s)$ and sends it to verifier


For each alleged message $m\in\{0,1\}^*$ and signature $(r,s)$, verifier

checks $r\in\mathbb F_q\setminus\{0\}$ and $s\in\mathbb F_q\setminus\{0\}$, rejects signature otherwise
computes $e=\operatorname{Hash}(m)$ in $\mathbb F_q$
computes $w=s^{-1}$ in $\mathbb F_q$
computes $a=w\cdot e$ and $b=w\cdot r$ in $\mathbb F_q$
computes $X=(a*G)\mathbin{\dot+}(b*Y)$ in $\mathbb G$ and if $X=\mathcal O$ rejects signature
accepts or rejects signature w.r.t. $m$ according to if $f(X)=r$ or not.



Argument that valid signatures are always accepted: in verifier's step 6, expanding:
$$\begin{align}
f(X)&=f\bigl((a*G)\mathbin{\dot+}(b*Y)\bigr)&&\text{per ver. 5}\\
&=f\bigl(((w\cdot e)*G)\mathbin{\dot+}((w\cdot r)*(x*G))\bigr)&&\text{per ver. 4 and gen.}\\
&=f\bigl((w\cdot(e+r\cdot x))*G\bigr)&&\text{per algebra in }\mathbb F_q\text{ and }\mathbb G\\
&=f\bigl((s^{-1}\cdot(e+r\cdot x))*G\bigr)&&\text{per ver. 3}\\
&=f\bigl(((k^{-1}\cdot(e+r\cdot x))^{-1}\cdot(e+r\cdot x))*G\bigr)&&\text{per sig. 4}\\
&=f\bigl(k*G\bigr)&&\text{per algebra in }\mathbb F_q\\
&=r&&\text{per sig. 3}
\end{align}$$
This proof is independent of what the ad-hoc function $f$ is! Any function $f$ making $g:\,\mathbb F_q\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb F_q$ would do from the standpoint of allowing verification. Thus we could construct $f$ by hashing to $\mathbb F_q$.
With $f$ modeled as a hash and if DDH holds in $\mathbb G$, it can be proven that the signature system is sEUF-CMA. That appears to stand for DSA, however ECDSA is not sEUF-CMA (but still appears to be EUF-CMA), which illustrates the limited confidence we should have in the conclusion of such proof, because it relies on an unwarranted assumption about $f$. Problem is that the restriction to X coordinate in the ad-hoc function $f$ of ECDSA implies $f(\dot-U)=U$, which makes it trivial to break second preimage of $f$. There are other regularities in the ad-hoc functions $f$ used in DSA and ECDSA, and arguments that they can't harm fly above my head (that's not to suggest they may not hold, and I'm even ready to accept that the regularity there is in the ad-hoc functions $f$ may improve security).

Especially interested in how can I get these $X_x$ or $R_x$ in ECDSA

You don't get that straight from algebra. That's part of the construction of the ad-hoc function $f:\,\mathbb G\setminus\{\mathcal O\}\to\mathbb F_q$.

EdDSA differs: a reasonably accurate description is possible in term of $\mathbb G$ with a representation of an element $U$ as a bitstring $\underline U$, the field $\mathbb F_q$, and a hash, without resorting to an ad-hoc function $f$. EdDSA internally builds an analog to $f$ on top of that $U\mapsto\underline U$ transformation and a hash; also this analog has additional inputs.
Another view is that EdDSA is a modern-textbook Schnorr signature (in the variant where the signature contains a representation of a group element rather than a short hash as is the case in the original Schnoor signature), instantiated in a subgroup of prime order $q$ of a twisted Edwards elliptic curve group on a prime field.
Note: The question does not accurately describe EdDSA (for example the creation of the public key actually involves a hash). For a mathematically-oriented description of the original EdDSA, see this (caveat: it uses $\ell$ where we have $q$). For the "standard", see RFC 8032.

# $\mathbb F_p$ is $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. That is, an element $U$ of field $\mathbb F_p$ for prime $p$ is an equivalence class of the equivalence relation on the ring of integers $\mathbb Z$ defined by: $u$ is equivalent to $u'$ when $u-u'$ is a multiple of $p$, noted $u\equiv u'\pmod p$. These $u$ and $u'$ are called integer representatives of $U$. They are elements of the set $U$, which contains infinetly many. To define $U\bmod q$ for $q\ne p$, DSA and ECDSA make it $u\bmod q$ for the uniquely defined $u\in\,[0,p)\cap U$. Using $u\in\,[(1-p)/2,(p-1)/2]\cap U$ leads to a different ad-hoc function $f$.

thank you very much for such a clear explanation! Perfect as always!
